# How to read basicHttpBinding defined in app.config file

Tags: c#, app-config, configurationmanager, basichttpbinding

I'm trying to figure out how to read how to read basicHttpBinding section defined in app.config file. I attempted to do it like I did the endpoint address but it does not work. Here is how I did my endpoint address:

```
private EndpointAddress EndPointAddy
{
    get
    {
        var config = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.serviceModel/Client") as ServiceModelSectionGroup;                
        foreach (ChannelEndpointElement endpoint in config.Client.Endpoints)
        {
            Uri address = endpoint.Address;

            if (address != null)
            {
                return new EndpointAddress(address);                         
            }          
        }
        return null;           
    }
}
```

Here is what I have tried with the BasicHttpBinding

```
private BasicHttpBinding Binding
{
    get
    {
        var config = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.serviceModel/Client") as ServiceModelSectionGroup;
        foreach (ChannelEndpointElement bindings in config.Bindings.BasicHttpBinding)
        {
            string binding = config.Bindings.BasicHttpBinding;

            if (config.Bindings.BasicHttpBinding != null)
            {
                return new BasicHttpBinding(config.Bindings.BasicHttpBinding);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

However I recieve an error that states:

> "foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type
>   'System.ServiceModel.Configuration.BasicHttpBindingCollectionElement'
>   because
>   'System.ServiceModel.Configuration.BasicHttpBindingCollectionElement'
>   does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'"

I've tried replacing ChannelEndpointElement with BasicHttpBindingElement but that doesn't help.  I'm at a loss how to do this correctly so that I get the same effect as the endpointAddress.

**Edit:**
I thought I had this fixed but all I did was get rid of the errors.  When I try to debug the program, I receive a

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object

at the following point:

```
foreach (ChannelEndpointElement bindings in config.Bindings.BasicHttpBinding.Bindings)
```

however, even though it fails on this line, I noticed that the line above it:

```
var config = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.serviceModel") as ServiceModelSectionGroup;
```

is null as well.  I'm not sure what it is I am doing wrong.

Comment: You need to foreach on config.Bindings.BasicHttpBinding.Bindings

Comment: @AmiramKorach It looks like I didn't go far enough "down the line".  That worked.  Thank you.