# Is there anything like "Configuration Context" in app.config

Tags: c#, .net, configuration, app-config, configuration-files

In our C# project I came across a situation where I would like to have something like a "Configuration Context" in the config files.

What I mean by that:

I would like something functionality like this (imaginary example)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>

    <ConfigurationContext name="Context1">
        <connectionStrings>
            <add name="AppConnStr" connectionString="..." providerName="..."/>
        </connectionStrings>
        <AppSettings>
            <add key="name" value="Config 1 Test!"/>
        </AppSettings>
    </ConfigurationContext>

    <ConfigurationContext name="Context2">
        <connectionStrings>
            <add name="AppConnStr" connectionString="..." providerName="..."/>
        </connectionStrings>
        <AppSettings>
            <add key="name" value="Config 2 Test!"/>
        </AppSettings>
    </ConfigurationContext>

</configuration>
```

Then I could use it like

```
var context1 = ConfigurationManager.GetContext("Context1");
var conn = new SqlConnection(context1.ConnectionStrings["AppConnStr"].ConnectionString);
```

meaning each "context" would be as if it was an app.config in it's own (with sections, section groups etc)...

Now what I do is I load two different app domains, each one with it's own config file. The reason is because almost all of the settings of the project are exposed to the code through public static Properties. To avoid heavy refactoring from static to instance properties I had to choose the multiple app domains solution.

Now that I have the time to do it, I would like to refactor the code to use Context objects that would implement the interfaces that would expose the config settings as instance properties, and get rid of the loading, unloading and shadow copying of the app domains...

**Is there a way to achieve such functionality in the .NET framework?**

Comment: Maybe GetSection..? (Never tried it.) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11459926/c-configuration-getsectionbasichttpbinding-not-reading-that-section-from-a ?

Comment: A section can appear only once (AppSettings for instance). I can always define multiple sections with different names but same types (NameValueFileSectionHandler) so I could have two AppSettings sections  with different names. But this is limited to each individual section, and needs custom sectionhandlers in order to "group" all sections under one "context".